# I can no longer debug classic asp code with visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, iis, asp-classic

I've finally found a way to debug classic asp code in visual studio 2008 ... but...

[has anybody been able to debug asp classic code with visual studio 2005 or later?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958968/has-anybody-been-able-to-debug-asp-classic-code-with-visual-studio-2005-or-later)

... but ...

it only lasted a few days...

I'm following these steps

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/DebugVBScriptVS2008.aspx

http://codepagoda.com/2009/04/30/debugging-classic-asp-with-visual-studio-2008-sp1-and-35-framework/

but now, when I do "attach process" I can no longer see the "Script, x86" process anymore...

so I can not debug classic asp code...

I tried restarting the machine, creating a new project, startgin from scrath, the only thing I haven't tried so far is to reinstall IIS...

any idea???

PLEASE HELP!!!!

edit: some info about my environment

Windows XP 2002 SP 3, IIS 5.1, Visual Studio 2008 9.0.30729.1 SP

Comment: It would help if you specified what O/S you are using?

Comment: I guess you need to host the site is IIS and attach the debugger to w3wp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely reason for this is because the process hasn't spun up yet.  You need to hit an ASP page first before IIS spins up the DLLHOST.exe in which it runs an application if you have that application set to have high isolation (recommended for debugging purposes).

Hence debugging bia attachment requires the you use the browser to ping an ASP page in your site first, then open the Attach to process list.

Comment: yeap, I was browsing the page, I tries with right-click, View in broser, and setting it as the start page and hitting F5... I could see a couple of dllhost.exe process, but none of them was of type "Script", I tried attaching to all of them but nothing happened...
I've just reinstalled IIS, but now I have to repair vs2008 installation.... yuck...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwesw3ee(VS.71).aspx#vxtbshttpservererrorsmanuallyattaching

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I fixed it out installing Service Pack 1 for my Visual Studio 2008. And now I attach to "inetinfo.exe" process instead of "dllhost.exe".

Answer (score 0):

The following steps might help you:

1. Host the site is IIS and make sure it's running
2. Change the Application Configuration to enable debugging [image]
3. Then Attach the debugger to w3wp (IIS worker process) [image]