# specified cast is not valid error on development but not on test server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oracle, asp-classic, iis-6

I have a .Net 2 solution with some asp classic pages.

I get a specified cast is not valid error when I access the page on my local.  Below is the vb function where I get the Error:

```
    Public Function Retrieve(ByVal vntSeqId As String, ByRef vntPart As String, ByRef vntPartKey As String, ByRef vntEntDate As String _
    , ByRef vntStatus As String, ByRef vntOrigGblId As String, ByRef vntOrigNetId As String, ByRef vntOrigName As String, ByRef vntOrigPhone As String _
    , ByRef vntOrigMs As String, ByRef vntReqType As String, ByRef vntPriority As String, ByRef vntAudBldg As String, ByRef vntRemarks As String _
    , ByRef vntMbldg As String, ByRef vntTlStk As String, ByRef vntTlDef As String, ByRef vntTlAud As String, ByRef vntOrdPend As String _
    , ByRef vntAction As String, ByRef vntCompGblId As String, ByRef vntCompNetId As String, ByRef vntCompName As String, ByRef vntCompPhone As String _
    , ByRef vntCompMs As String, ByRef vntActTk As String, ByRef vntComp As String, ByRef vntCompDate As String, ByRef vntOffHold As String _
    , ByRef vntQtyShp As String, ByRef vntShpDt As String, ByRef vntCartons As String, ByRef vntComments As String, ByRef vntRowlock As String _
    , ByRef vntOnHoldDt As String, ByRef vntOnHoldGblId As String, ByRef vntOffHoldDt As String, ByRef vntOffHoldGblId As String, ByRef vntOnHoldName As String _
    , ByRef vntOffHoldName As String, ByRef vntStatDesc As String, ByRef vntReqTypeDesc As String, ByRef vntPriorDesc As String, ByRef vntAudBldgDesc As String _
    , ByRef vntActionDesc As String, ByRef vntActTkDesc As String, ByRef vntDateCde As String, ByRef strSamplingPlan As String, ByRef vntFO As String _
    , ByRef vntPO As String, ByRef vntIblId As String, ByRef vntOnHoldNetId As String, ByRef vntOffHoldNetId As String, ByRef vntOrigEmail As String _
    , ByRef vntCompEmail As String, ByRef vntTlHold As String, ByRef vntImportAuditInd As String _
    , ByRef vntErrorNumber As Integer, ByRef vntErrorDesc As String) As Boolean


        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

        Dim blnRC As Boolean
        Dim vntTemp As String = String.Empty
        Dim intCount As Integer
        Dim vntPrcntPcs As String
        Dim vntSampPlan As String

        If vntSeqId = "" Then
            Err.Raise(267, , "Sequence ID not specified")
        End If

        Dim objCallSP As New clsCallSP
        blnRC = objCallSP.CallSP("QneEngAudit.RetrieveAudit", vntErrorNumber, vntErrorDesc _
            , "I", vntSeqId _
            , "O", vntPart, "O", vntPartKey, "O", vntEntDate, "O", vntStatus, "O", vntOrigGblId, "O", vntOrigNetId, "O", vntReqType _
            , "O", vntPriority, "O", vntAudBldg, "OL", vntRemarks, "O", vntMbldg, "O", vntTlStk, "O", vntTlDef, "O", vntTlAud, "O", vntOrdPend _
            , "O", vntAction, "O", vntCompGblId, "O", vntActTk, "O", vntComp, "O", vntCompDate, "O", vntOffHold, "O", vntQtyShp, "O", vntShpDt _
            , "O", vntCartons, "OL", vntComments, "O", vntRowlock, "O", vntOnHoldDt, "O", vntOnHoldGblId, "O", vntOffHoldDt _
            , "O", vntOffHoldGblId, "O", vntImportAuditInd)
        If Not (blnRC AndAlso vntErrorNumber = 0) Then
            Err.Raise(vntErrorNumber, , vntErrorDesc)
        End If

        vntPart = objCallSP.OutParams(0)
        vntPartKey = objCallSP.OutParams(1)
        vntEntDate = objCallSP.OutParams(2)
        vntStatus = objCallSP.OutParams(3)
        vntOrigGblId = objCallSP.OutParams(4)
        vntOrigNetId = objCallSP.OutParams(5)
        vntReqType = objCallSP.OutParams(6)
        vntPriority = objCallSP.OutParams(7)
        vntAudBldg = objCallSP.OutParams(8)
        vntRemarks = objCallSP.OutParams(9)
        vntMbldg = objCallSP.OutParams(10)
        vntTlStk = objCallSP.OutParams(11)
        vntTlDef = objCallSP.OutParams(12)
        vntTlAud = objCallSP.OutParams(13)
        vntOrdPend = objCallSP.OutParams(14)
        vntAction = objCallSP.OutParams(15)
        vntCompGblId = objCallSP.OutParams(16)
        vntActTk = objCallSP.OutParams(17)
        vntComp = objCallSP.OutParams(18)
        vntCompDate = objCallSP.OutParams(19)
        vntOffHold = objCallSP.OutParams(20)
        vntQtyShp = objCallSP.OutParams(21)
        vntShpDt = objCallSP.OutParams(22)
        vntCartons = objCallSP.OutParams(23)
        vntComments = objCallSP.OutParams(24)
        vntRowlock = objCallSP.OutParams(25)
        vntOnHoldDt = objCallSP.OutParams(26)
        vntOnHoldGblId = objCallSP.OutParams(27)
        vntOffHoldDt = objCallSP.OutParams(28)
        vntOffHoldGblId = objCallSP.OutParams(29)
        vntImportAuditInd = objCallSP.OutParams(30)

        If vntPart = "" OrElse vntPartKey = "" Then
            Err.Raise(281, , "Part number or part key ID not found for specified sequence ID")
        End If

        If vntOrigGblId <> "" Then
            blnRC = (New clsAssociate).RetrieveByGblId(vntOrigGblId, vntOrigName, vntOrigNetId, vntOrigEmail, vntOrigPhone, vntOrigMs, vntTemp, vntTemp, vntErrorNumber, vntErrorDesc)
        End If

        If vntOrigGblId = "" AndAlso vntOrigNetId <> "" Then
            blnRC = (New clsAssociate).RetrieveByNetId(vntOrigNetId, vntOrigName, vntOrigGblId, vntOrigEmail, vntOrigPhone, vntOrigMs, vntTemp, vntTemp, vntErrorNumber, vntErrorDesc)
        End If

        If vntStatus <> "" Then
            blnRC = (New clsStatus).Retrieve(vntStatus, vntTemp, vntStatDesc, vntErrorNumber, vntErrorDesc)
            If vntErrorNumber <> 0 Then
                Err.Raise(vntErrorNumber, , vntErrorDesc)
            End If
        End If

        If vntAudBldg <> "" Then
            blnRC = (New clsGlobalData).Retrieve(vntAudBldg, vntTemp, vntTemp, vntTemp, vntTemp, vntAudBldgDesc, vntTemp, vntTemp, vntErrorNumber, vntErrorDesc)
            If vntErrorNumber <> 0 Then
                Err.Raise(vntErrorNumber, , vntErrorDesc)
            End If
        End If

        If vntCompGblId <> "" Then
            blnRC = (New clsAssociate).RetrieveByGblId(vntCompGblId, vntCompName, vntCompNetId, vntCompEmail, vntCompPhone, vntCompMs, vntTemp, vntTemp, vntErrorNumber, vntErrorDesc)
        End If

        If vntOnHoldGblId <> "" Then
            blnRC = (New clsAssociate).RetrieveByGblId(vntOnHoldGblId, vntOnHoldName, vntOnHoldNetId, vntTemp, vntTemp, vntTemp, vntTemp, vntTemp, vntErrorNumber, vntErrorDesc)
        End If

        If vntOffHoldGblId <> "" Then
            blnRC = (New clsAssociate).RetrieveByGblId(vntOffHoldGblId, vntOffHoldName, vntOffHoldNetId, vntTemp, vntTemp, vntTemp, vntTemp, vntTemp, vntErrorNumber, vntErrorDesc)
        End If

        If vntAction <> "" Then
            blnRC = (New clsDisposition).RetrieveCategory(vntAction, vntActionDesc, vntErrorNumber, vntErrorDesc)
            If vntErrorNumber <> 0 Then
                Err.Raise(vntErrorNumber, , vntErrorDesc)
            End If
        End If

        If vntReqType <> "" Then
            blnRC = (New clsRequestType).Retrieve(vntReqType, vntReqTypeDesc, vntErrorNumber, vntErrorDesc)
            If vntErrorNumber <> 0 Then
                Err.Raise(vntErrorNumber, , vntErrorDesc)
            End If
        End If

        If vntPriority <> "" Then
            blnRC = (New clsPriority).Retrieve(vntPriority, vntPriorDesc, vntErrorNumber, vntErrorDesc)
            If vntErrorNumber <> 0 Then
                Err.Raise(vntErrorNumber, , vntErrorDesc)
            End If
        End If

        If vntActTk <> "" Then
            blnRC = (New clsAuditType).Retrieve(vntActTk, vntTemp, vntActTkDesc, vntErrorNumber, vntErrorDesc)
            If vntErrorNumber <> 0 Then
                Err.Raise(vntErrorNumber, , vntErrorDesc)
            End If
        End If

        Dim vntArray As Object(,) = (New clsAddFields).List(vntSeqId, vntErrorNumber, vntErrorDesc)
        If Not IsNothing(vntArray) Then
            vntSampPlan = ""
            vntPrcntPcs = ""
            vntDateCde = ""
            vntFO = ""
            vntPO = ""
            vntIblId = ""
            vntTlHold = ""
            For intCount = 0 To UBound(vntArray, 2)
                Select Case CInt(vntArray(0, intCount))
                    Case 1
                        If vntDateCde = "" Then
                            vntDateCde = Trim(vntArray(1, intCount).ToString())
                        Else
                            vntDateCde &= "," & Trim(vntArray(1, intCount).ToString())
                        End If
                    Case 2
                        If vntFO = "" Then
                            vntFO = Trim(vntArray(1, intCount).ToString())
                        Else
                            vntFO &= "," & Trim(vntArray(1, intCount).ToString())
                        End If
                    Case 3
                        If vntPO = "" Then
                            vntPO = Trim(vntArray(1, intCount).ToString())
                        Else
                            vntPO &= "," & vntArray(1, intCount).ToString()
                        End If
                    Case 5
                        If vntIblId = "" Then
                            vntIblId = Trim(vntArray(1, intCount).ToString())
                        Else
                            vntIblId &= "," & Trim(vntArray(1, intCount).ToString())
                        End If
                    Case 7
                        If vntTlHold = "" Then
                            vntTlHold = Trim(vntArray(1, intCount).ToString())
                        Else
                            vntTlHold &= "," & Trim(vntArray(1, intCount).ToString())
                        End If
                    Case 8
                        If vntSampPlan = "" Then
                            vntSampPlan = Trim(vntArray(1, intCount).ToString())
                        Else
                            vntSampPlan &= "," & Trim(vntArray(1, intCount).ToString())
                        End If
                    Case 9
                        If vntPrcntPcs = "" Then
                            vntPrcntPcs = Trim(vntArray(1, intCount).ToString())
                        Else
                            vntPrcntPcs &= "," & Trim(vntArray(1, intCount).ToString())
                        End If

                        'Case 10 'Audit Conversation Complete in WCS
                        '    Dim vntAuditConversationCompleteInWCS As String
                        '    vntAuditConversationCompleteInWCS = Trim(vntArray(1, intCount).ToString())
                End Select
            Next
            If vntSampPlan <> "" Then
                strSamplingPlan = vntSampPlan & "," & vntPrcntPcs
            End If
        Else
            vntDateCde = ""
            vntFO = ""
            vntPO = ""
            vntIblId = ""
            vntTlHold = ""
            vntSampPlan = ""
            'vntAuditConversationCompleteInWCS = ""
        End If

        vntErrorNumber = 0
        vntErrorDesc = ""

        Return True

ErrorHandler:

        vntErrorNumber = Err.Number
        vntErrorDesc = String.Format("{0} ({1})", Err.Description, Utility.QualifiedMethodName())

        Return False

    End Function
```

At first, I thought the problem is with the source code and we were thinking the source code we have is different with the ones deployed on test and prod servers.  But when I tried to upload it on the test server, I don't get the specified cast is not valid error.

Any ideas what to check with the setup or configs?  registered assemblies maybe?

Comment: Can you post the code in question? Or a simplified version that exhibits the error?

Answer (score 1):

It may be data related. Do all environments use the same data source?

BTW, don't you have the required environment for debugging to find the problem?

**Edit After Comments**

Then try to debug it by old style asp debugging technique.

Add a code like Err.Raise(0, , "Code running to here without any problem"). If you get the cast error rather than this one then you have problem with the codes before it :)

At least it helps you to find the code causes the error.

Comment: development and test server are using the same test db

Comment: are the config files the same? It may be a wrong data in the config file which is tried to cast. (such as a string value rather than integer for an application setting in the web config file)

Comment: yeah, i don't.. sort of.. I have visual studio but since the page being accessed are asp pages, I almost can't debug... not everything.  When I attached the process, I can debug the asp files but not the vb classes being called.

Comment: I also tried to make a similar web.config file on my local, but still the same

Comment: Have you ever tried to attach both DllHost.exe and w3wp.exe (or aspnet worker process in the older windows OS) to be able to debug both? I am not sure but i think it may work. Just look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730229/step-through-debugging-for-classic-asp-with-vs2008) for debugging classic asp with VS2008.

Comment: unfortunately, I have some license issues for installing vs2008 in the office.  I'll have to stick with vs2005 for now.  Anyway, thanks for the advise orka.  My project coordinator and I are really hating this current project.

Comment: I understand your difficulties. How about checking [VS2005 ASP Debugging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958968/has-anybody-been-able-to-debug-asp-classic-code-with-visual-studio-2005-or-later) thread. Hope it helps.